# IP Scanner to scan a remote network through SSH

Tags: remote-access, ssh, network-scanner

I'm using Putty to log into a remote network via an SSH tunnel, and I set a Forwarded Port in Putty to be able to use Firefox on the remote network by setting the Firefox proxy settings to that port.

Now I'm looking if there's a program like Advanced IP Scanner or so, to scan all devices on the network, that can be set to use this SOCKS Proxy to scan the devices locally on the remote network instead of my local network.

Any recommendation appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a ssh server running, why don't you install *nmap* on it and run it remotely?
Nmap is normally the choice to go for things like this.
You can't tunnel nmap over ssh because it sends packages that will be filtered by your ssh server. So i think it's nearly impossible to scan ports over a ssh tunnel.

After doing some research on that topic, I've found a little tool here [portscan over ssh](http://edge-security.blogspot.de/2011/06/scanning-ports-through-ssh-port.html). Maybe it works for you but I've not tested it yet. But it sounds like it could work.
Good luck with testing!

Comment: The SSH server is on the router and I can't really add things to it. That scanSSH seems to be exactly what I'm looking for but unfortunately it isn't a compiled project, only source code available with I have no clue how to use.

Comment: Ok. I'll have a look this afternoon and i'll write back a comment hete!

Comment: Hope you'll get something...this would be extremely useful for my work.

Comment: Oh wait.  It's plain python so you have to install python and you are good to go.

Comment: I'm not really sure to do that but I might figure it out if needed. But now I gave another look at it, and I see that it scans "port" for "a host" on the network. What I want is to get a list of all devices on that network with some info about then (IP, MAC, and there more the better.)

Comment: What's about the router? Don't you have DHCP enabled and can't you see the devices with IP and MAC?

Comment: I do have a device list on the router, but these tools always have a lot clearer information, like manufacturer and so.

Answer (score -1):

Angry IP Scanner and go into settings where you can specify specific ports

Comment: On the local or remote machine?

Comment: Also, please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality